# Stream live webcam AV feed to wowza using FFMPEG

Tags: php, ffmpeg, webcam, live-streaming, wowza

I have been trying to find out how to live stream my webcam feed to my wowza server. I am trying to make a web application in php that lets users stream live video through their webcam.

I am confused, if i need to install FFMPEG in every user's computer that uses my application or just installing it in my web server will do??

Thank you in advance. A little help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user's webcam stream is on the *client-side* and the problem is getting that stream from each client to your server so having FFmpeg on the server won't help you a lot.

This is achieved by using some form of browser plugin, like **Flash** or **Silverlight** and hopefully in a near future using directly [HTML5 / WebRTC](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/).

For Wowza you can use the **FlashRTMPPlayer** . Here's the documentation showing [how to record a webcam feed](http://www.wowza.com/resources/3.6.0/examples/WebcamRecording/FlashRTMPPlayer/player.html) and how to setup a [live video chat application](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?42-How-to-set-up-live-video-chat) which is probably a good starting point for your live streaming application.

There are some other libraries that can do the same. Search for webcam Flash RTMP capture.

Comment: Thank you for clearing my doubt. I was trying not to use Flash actually, but i guess there's no other way as of now, Right??
Will do some research on FlashRTMPPlayer.